Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in com.spring.Config:Failedtoinstantiateorg.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate
Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in com.spring.Config: Failed to instantiate \[org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate\]: Factory method 'hibernateTemplate' threw exception with message: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in com.spring.Config: Failed to instantiate \[org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate\]: Factory method 'hibernateTemplate' threw exception with message: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648)

@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource getDataSource() {
    
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/todo");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("root");
        return ds;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        factory.setHibernateProperties(prop);
        factory.setAnnotatedClasses(Student.class);
        return factory.getObject();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate() {
        
        return new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory());
    }

}

public class App {
public static void main(String\[\] args) {
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

        HibernateTemplate st = (HibernateTemplate)context.getBean("hibernateTemplate"
                `your text`+ "");
        System.out.println(st);
    }

}


Can you show the full stacktrace?

Don't use HibernateTemplate use SessionFactory.getCurrentSession instead. The use of HibernateTemplate has been discouraged in favor of that for years already. It has no added benefit anymore.
